# Background image: all-visible, original dimensions?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2007

When I add a background image to Powerpoint, it always scales such that the dimension are perfect, but a part of the image is cut off.  How can I get the background to be **the correct dimensions** but also **completely visible**?  I want to create a **correct-dimensions** image slideshow using Powerpoint.  I want students to be able to see *all* images, *completely*, with *the correct dimensions*?

Comment: Talking specifically about background images and hoping to configure PowerPoint to automatically do locked aspect ratio wherein the image does not exceed the resolution of the monitor in any dimension.

Answer (score 1):

By the **correct dimensions** you might mean **keep aspect ratio**. See right click, format, size, scale, *Lock aspect ratio*.

Or you can resize the images by hand, holding the shift key (keep ratio) or ctrl key (keep center). (Or both)

Comment: That's nice, but I'm trying to do this specifically for background images.

Comment: Edit **Master slide**, to always contain the image. If you want multiple backgrounds in your presentation, create more Master slides. But don't use backgrounds as the _content_, they are meant for _styling_. If you want your slides border-less, use resizing/cropping.